# Unresolved reference POST request and implementing custom headers/body Kotlin Jetpack Compose Retrofit

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, retrofit

I have errors and questions with the following code:

Data Class:

```
data class AccountCredentials(
    val email: String,
    val password: String
)
```

View Model:

```
class ServerDataViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val _data = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val data: LiveData<String> = _data

    fun createAccount(email: String, password: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                val response = RetrofitInstance.api.createAccount(AccountCredentials(email, password))
                if (response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null) {
                    _data.postValue(response.body())
                }
            } catch (e: HttpException) {
            } catch (e: IOException) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
interface ApiInterface {
    @POST("/create-accouunt")
    suspend fun createAccount(@Body credentials: AccountCredentials): Call<AccountCredentials>
}
```

For some reason, with a GET request, there's no errors, but with the above POST request I get an error with `.isSuccesful` and `.body()`. I'm also unsure as how to set get body and header parameters from the view model.

Edit: What happens with the variable when there's not a @Header or @body declaration in the API Interface? When there is a header or body declaration how do you pass those parameters when calling the function?

Comment: I know its a simple question, but is this supposed to be like this?
"@POST("/create-accouunt")" with 2 uu? Just to make sure.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, but the problem I'm having is how to declare headers and body parameters in functions in the interface and passing those parameters to the interface functions from a View Model.